# call a zsh alias in the mathematica notebook

Tags: command-line

## I want to call this `zsh` alias in a mathematica cell?

my `zsh` alias is called `testAlias`

[image]

I have tried many mathematica functions and found that `ReadList` can send strings to my `zsh` shell (or internal command line anyhow)

Unfortunately alias's don't work.

[image]
Is there any way I can run `testAlias` in mathematica?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken the process where the alias was defined was closed after the run through `ReadList`. Check out `StartProcess`. Then you can use `WriteLine[procObj,"testAlias"]` and read it back in with `ReadString[procObj, EndOfBuffer]`.

Answer (score 1):

## Oh_My_Zsh, iTerm, Zsh, called from Mathematica Notebook

to help future strugglers here is @b3m2a1's comment expanded into a function which sends commands to the Oh_My_Zsh environment enabling scripting/Automation using mathematica string manipulation.

[image]

```
zshTerminal[commandString_] := Module[
{process},
process = StartProcess[{$SystemShell}];
WriteLine[process, ". ~/.zshrc"];
WriteLine[process, commandString];
WriteLine[process, "exit\n"];
Print[ReadString[process]]
];
```

---

```
zshTerminal["ls"]
```

[image]

```
zshTerminal["testFunction"]
```

[image]

---

```
zshTerminal["testAlias"]
```

Comment: One thing you may want to do is either cache your zsh process to avoid having to spin up a new one each call (just make sure to check it's still running via `ProcessStatus` before trying to use it) or close it using `KillProcess` when you're done so you don't get a backlog of `ProcessObjects` under `Processes[]`.